# Speed up MySQL ORDER-BY when where has OR

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 million rows, a "channel" column and a "time" column.

I have individual indexes on channel and time, as well as a combined index on channel+time.

This is instantaneous:

```
select * from table where channel = 5 order by time desc limit 10
```

But this takes 12-15 seconds:

```
select * from table where channel = 4 OR channel = 5 order by time desc limit 10
```

The explain says that the combined index is used for both, but the difference is that filesort is invoked on the second (I assume to do the merge sort between the two selects)

Is there a good way to speed this up, or should I just do two selects and merge the results later? (Because almost anything can merge-sort 10 items in less than 15 seconds these days)

Comment: can you include the explain plan detail (as text)? How many channels are there? (is the cardinality very low),

Comment: `|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | range | i_ch_time,i_ch | i_ch_time | 2       | NULL | 376251 | Using where; Using filesort |`

Comment: And the cardinality is on the order of dozens.

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases, especially mysql, are notorious for their lack of optimization to use index access for *both* sides of an `OR`.

In this case, you can use `IN (...)` to give a single expression that *will* use the index:

```
select * from table
where channel in (4, 5)
order by time desc
limit 10
```

Even though *logically* it returns exactly the same data, mysql will use the index for both values when coded as an `IN`, but won't if coded as an `OR`.

Comment: Still takes 15 seconds to run and uses filesort when using in (4,5)

Comment: @atmatthewat what is the datatype of the `channel` column? Do you have an index on it?

Comment: smallint(5) unsigned and yes there's an index on channel and there's a combined index (channel, time)

Comment: @atmatthewat I could be a cardinality problem: If there are only a small number of different values for channel, it's faster to do a full table scan than use the index. Also, the number of rows in channel 4 might be much larger than channel 5, remembering that *all* the rows must be accessed and sorted *before* the top 10 are returned. Try running the first query but with channel = 4 and if it takes a long time for only channel 4 you'll have your answer.

Comment: both channel = 4 and channel = 5 are instant. 4 OR5, or in(4,5) are 15 seconds.

Comment: Try running `analyze table mytable`, then try the query again.